# how to remove the space between the lines(rows) of a wrap widget (flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

This is my code for wrap widget which is having multiple material button representing tags, i don't know why there is a vertical space between each new row in the wrap widget

```
    Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: [
                        MaterialButton(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          minWidth: 1,
                          height: 25,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            "#software",
                            style: TextStyle(color: defaultColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          minWidth: 1,
                          height: 25,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            "#software",
                            style: TextStyle(color: defaultColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          minWidth: 1,
                          height: 25,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            "#software",
                            style: TextStyle(color: defaultColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          minWidth: 1,
                          height: 25,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            "#software",
                            style: TextStyle(color: defaultColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          minWidth: 1,
                          height: 25,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            "#software",
                            style: TextStyle(color: defaultColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          minWidth: 1,
                          height: 25,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            "#software",
                            style: TextStyle(color: defaultColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

this is a picture describing the vertical space between the line , i reached a solution by set the running space to negative values and that worked for me, but i feel like its a bad practice[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZeXl.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `MaterialButton` directly. Use one of its descendants: `ElevatedButton`, `TextButton` or `OutlinedButton`.

In your case, `TextButton` is the closet to what you want to achieve, so you can use that as a starting point and then further customize its `style`.

Or, if you just want to allow clicking on the blue text, use `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` instead of using buttons.

Comment: thanks! , InkWell()  worked for me with Text() as a child.

Comment: @KhaledMortaja You are welcome! I just realized the typo I made: `TextButton` is the closest to what you want (but it still adds padding). You can also consider `GestureDetector` if you don't like the "ink splash" effect.. so yeah, whatever suits your needs :P

Answer (score 2):

you can use two property here for controlling the space

1. spacing
2. runSpacing

please test it and share with us about the result.

Comment: spacing works good for horizontal space, runspacing works good with negative values ,but if i set it to zero it wont work :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use more common buttons such as
https://www.notion.so/BUTTONS-IN-FLUTTER-f596d17ba17f418381b30ed140cd9239
and I would create a generalized button sending as parameters what I need from each button, so as not to generate more unnecessary code, you could also use column or row with mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
to align your buttons.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks!, its not a live code,  i am just testing the wrap widget ,of course i will use   generalized button instead of repeating the same code